# Emitting an event to all sockets in namespace in room, except sender

Tags: socket.io

With Socket.IO,
Upon receiving an event from a socket, I'd like to emit an event: 
to all sockets within a namespace - different than the current namespace - and that are in a room name -
designated by an option on the event, **except** to the socket I received the event from:

```js
io.of('namespace-a').on('connection', socket=> {
   socket.on('someevent', data=> {
       // I'd LIKE for this to *not* emit to `socket`
       io.of('namespace-b').to(data.roomId).emit('anotherevent', { ... });
   });
});
```

I couldn't find a way in the emit cheatsheets.

Comment: doesn't the code work?

Comment: @inodeska It works, but it also emits to `socket` and I don't want it to emit to it.